# Using .scss files as modules without naming them with .modules create-react-app

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, sass

I created a new app using create-react-app, and added scss to the project (simply ran npm install node-sass)

Now, when I want to use a .scss as a module, I have to name the file x.module.scss.

How can make every .scss file to automatically considered a module?

desired result example:
import styles from './test.scss'
.
.
.

currently I have to do this:
import styles from './test.module.scss'
.
.
.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

run -> react-scripts eject
GOTO -> /config/webpack.config.dev.js

Comment: Hey Asim, I figured out it has something to do with the webpack configuration, but before I run eject I'd like to get a more detailed answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just created a `create-react-app` application and added `node-sass`. You can see the versions below:

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "test-sass",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I changed the **.css** files to **.scss** files without the `module` keyword, and it works fine like a charm.

I guess maybe you have check the versions or other configuration. The eject is not necessary here. it is a build-in feature.